# Trying to create a simple link caching extension but failing

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a simple extension that creates an array that persists between pages and tabs and stores every image link with a specific class from the web page. When I click on the extension button a small html page generates the preview of each image that was stored in the array with a link to the anchor tag around it.

Hello, I am new to chrome extensions and I am trying to make a basic image stripper that throws all images with the matching class into an array from all tabs when each page is loaded. Here is my code.

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Link Viewer",
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version" : 2,
    "browser_action" : 
    {
        "default_popup" : "history.html",
        "default_icon" : "icon.png"
    },
    "background" : {"scripts" : ["persistent.js"]},
    "content_scripts" :
    [
        {
            "matches" : ["http://*/*"],
            "js" : ["injection.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

history.html

```
<h1>Image Viewer</h1>
<div id="list">
    <!-- Show Listed Images Here -->
</div>

injection.js

    // Executes every page load
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("img");
    var imageLinks = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
    {
        imageLinks.push(elements[i].firstChild.src);
    }
    chrome.extension.sendRequest(imageLinks);
```

persistent.js

```
// This script gets run once when the browser is started

// Declare Persistent Image Array

var gifArray = [];

// Create an event listener for when requests are returned from the injection script
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener
(
    function(linksReturned)
    {
        // Loop through each returned link
        for(var i = 0; i < linksReturned.length; i++)
        {
            var exists = false;
            // loop through each link in the array and make sure it doesn't exist
            for(var x = 0; x < gifArray.length; x++)
            {
                if(gifArray[x] == linksReturned[i])
                {
                    gifArray.splice(x,1); // Remove that index from the array
                    exists = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(exists == false)
            {
                gifArray.push(linksReturned[i]);
            }
        }
        // Links are stored and ready to be displayed on web page
    }
);

// Popup HTML page when someone clicks on HTML button
window.onload = function()
{
    var div = document.getElementById("list");
    // Loop through each GIF and add to the list
    for(var i = 0; i < gifArray.length; i++)
    {
        // Create the anchor element
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        // Create the image element
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.setAttribute("src",gifArray[i]);
        // Put the image inside of the anchor
        a.appendChild(img);
        // Put the anchor inside the div
        div.appendChild(a);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I have a global list of every image with the class img indexed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the code `window.onload = { .... }` in persistent.js doesn't work for your popup.

You must separate it by `persistent.js` and `popup.js`, and `popup.js` must be included into the `history.html` as a script.

Like this,

### history.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <h1>Image Viewer</h1>
  <div id="list">
      <!-- Show Listed Images Here -->
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

### popup.js

```
// Popup HTML page when someone clicks on HTML button
window.onload = function()
{  
    chrome.extension.sendRequest({type: "getImageLinks"}, function(response) {
      var div = document.getElementById("list");
      // Loop through each GIF and add to the list
      for(var i = 0; i < response.gifArray.length; i++)
      {
          // Create the anchor element
          var a = document.createElement("a");
          // Create the image element
          var img = document.createElement("img");
          img.setAttribute("src", response.gifArray[i]);
          // Put the image inside of the anchor
          a.appendChild(img);
          // Put the anchor inside the div
          div.appendChild(a);
      }      
    });
}
```

### persistent.js

```
// This script gets run once when the browser is started

// Declare Persistent Image Array

var gifArray = [];

// Create an event listener for when requests are returned from the injection script
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener
(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
      if (request.type == 'storeImageLinks')
      {
          var linksReturned = request.imageLinks;
          for(var i = 0; i < linksReturned.length; i++)
          {
              var exists = false;
              // loop through each link in the array and make sure it doesn't exist
              for(var x = 0; x < gifArray.length; x++)
              {
                  if(gifArray[x] == linksReturned[i])
                  {
                      exists = true;
                      break;
                  }
              }
              if(exists == false)
              {
                  gifArray.push(linksReturned[i]);
              }
          }
          // Links are stored and ready to be displayed on web page     
      }
      else if (request.type == 'getImageLinks')
      {
          sendResponse({gifArray: gifArray});
      }
    }
);
```

### injection.js

```
// Executes every page load
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("img");
    var imageLinks = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
    {
        imageLinks.push(elements[i].firstChild.src);
    }
    chrome.extension.sendRequest({type: "storeImageLinks", imageLinks : imageLinks});
```

[Here is my demo extension. (crx)](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39457223/ocanal/stackoverflow/2/LinkViewer.crx)

[Extension files in archive (rar)](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39457223/ocanal/stackoverflow/2/LinkViewer.rar)

To try it,

- open [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982367/trying-to-create-a-simple-link-caching-extension-but-failing/17984548) page
- click the exntension icon

you will see the google logo on the popup.

Comment: I understand where you are going now. I still can't seem to get this to work even if I use your code. Is there anything else I would need to do? Thanks for such an in depth reply btw.

Comment: are you sure about image container class? Is that someting like this `<div class="img"><img src="http://blablalba.png"></div>` Because I tried this code and it's working.

Comment: Its not working and its driving me nuts. Would it be possible to zip exactly what you have including the test file you used? If yours doesn't work its gotta be chrome or something. Maybe its even adblock.

Comment: Ok, I've added the demo to my answer below.

Comment: Now it is working! Thank you! I think I may need to play with it a bit more to get it work for a live feed, but you have led me on my way!